# How to selectively extract the data within an HTML tag

Tags: kotlin, jsoup

I am trying to extract data using Jsoup from a list element which looks like

```html
<li>"Peanut"<span>FREE</span></li>
```

Now when I'm trying to extract this, I am getting "Peanut FREE", whereas I want "Peanut".

How to do this in Jsoup?

Here is my code

```
    val url = "..."
    val document = Jsoup.connect(url).get()
    val body = document.body()
    val elements = body.getElementsByTag("li")
    Log.d("TAG_TAG_TAG", "Noo")
    for (i in elements) {
        Log.d("TAG_TAG_TAG", i.text())
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
val body = document.body()
val elements = body.select("li")
elements.select("span").remove()
for (i in elements) {
    println(i.text())
}
```